# Replace empty string with 0 in array

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays

I have a grid. When I enter some numeric values in that grid, it is saved in array.

```
                RegArrayLoopEL = RegArrayEL[a].Split('ô');
```

Now In case an array has empty string "" I have to replace it with 0
One way that I can do is

```
                if (RegArrayLoopEL[1] == "")
                {
                    RegArrayLoopEL[1] = "0";
                }
```

But for that I will have to use a lot of if conditions for every array. Is there any alternative for it? or any other way this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it on assignment:

```
RegArrayLoopEL = RegArrayEL[a].Split('ô').Select(str => str == "" ? "0" : str).ToArray();
```

You could create a function or delegate to clean it up a bit and make it so if you change the logic you just need to change it one place:

```
string[] ReplaceEmptyStrings(IEnumerable<string> strings) =>
    strings.Select(str => str == "" ? "0" : str).ToArray();
```

And then your assignments would be:

```
RegArrayLoopEL = ReplaceEmptryStrings(RegArrayEL[a].Split('ô'));
```